# Regular Expression Syntax for URL extraction

Tags: regex, url, syntax, jmeter

I need to extract the string to the right of the equal sign character in an Apache Jmeter project. I am not familiar with Regular Expression syntax at all, but I think this would be the easiest way to extract it. The url is:  `https://myserver.com:portnum/im;jsessionid=48E10C95151BFB84D795C90FBC31E8E6` 
I only need the string to the right of the equal sign, not including the equal sign. My question is, what regular expression should I use to extract the string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as `=(\w+)`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Demo]

References:

- [JMeter - Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Also be aware that there are "smarter" ways of handling [JSESSIONID](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html):

- In case if it comes as a Cookie you can get its value via [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- If it is being passed as an URL parameter you could use [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier)